# Nodes don't get forgotten

Tags: aerospike, asadmin

Running `ascli` I get a lot of `2016-07-14 15:44:07 WARN AEROSPIKE_ERR_TIMEOUT` warnings. I see that in `asadm` -> `info network` there are 13 nodes listed, but only 4 are active (which is correct; it's a 4 node cluster). Those other 9 nodes are either old hosts which have left the cluster ages ago, or other IP address for hosts which are (correctly) part of the cluster. The cluster works fine otherwise. All nodes run 3.7.4.1.

Is there a way to remove all those old hosts? `dun`ning them doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [services-alumni-reset](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info#services-alumni-reset) command. Basically Aerospike doesn't know you do not intend to return these nodes in the future so it keeps these entries in its internal alumni list to allow tools to detect nodes that are missing from the cluster. The reset commands syncs the alumni list with the active node list and may be used whenever a node has been permanently removed from the cluster.

NB, the alumni list doesn't affect the Aerospike servers or clients, it is provided specifically for troubleshooting and used by various diagnostic tools.

Comment: Excellent, that helps. it still has some address in the list which I don't want in there, but those addresses belong to other interfaces on the machines, I will see if binding to the correct interface will help. Thanks!

Comment: (`asinfo -v 'service'` shows me it indeed binds to too many interfaces, so that's easy enough to fix as well)

Comment: Yes, if not specified, all interfaces are advertised to clients. You will need to run the service-alumni-reset after the config change to remove the newly dead entities.